# How to replace with complex rules in word by vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace some fixed point number into percentage in a word document, like the following

```
0.1234 -> 12.3%
```

I wrote the following code

```
Sub DoReplace()
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "0.[0-9]*^13"
        .Replacement.Text = Str(Val("^&") * 100) + "%" + "^13"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

I think `^&` means the original selection string, so I can perform some transformation on that, but it seems not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do math that way in a Find/Replace. In any event, you don't need to:

```
Sub DoReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "0.([0-9]{2})([0-9][0-9])@^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1.\2%^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "0.([0-9]{2})([0-9])^13"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1.\20%^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = "0([0-9].[0-9]@%)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The above process *truncates* the output at 2 digits after the decimal point. To *round* the output, something more complex is needed:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "0.[0-9]@^13"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    .End = .End - 1
    .Text = Format(.Text, "0.00%")
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what's the  effect of the second replacement from `"0([0-9].[0-9]@%)"` to `\1`? I tried this, and the first replacement already change `0.123456` into `12.3456%`? Meanwhile, I tried `0.([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]@)^13` in order to implement something like `.2f` formatter in C, however it does not work with `0.1`, which is not long enough to provide at least 4 digits to pattern match

Comment: The "0([0-9].[0-9]@%)" to "\1" removes leading zeros so that, for example, 0.0123 ends up as 1.23%, not 01.23%. I don't understand your second issue.

Comment: I want to this to print only two digits after. For example, I want  `12.34%` rather than `12.345678%`